# Можно ли сократить стандартное условие в методе записи переменной name=(name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем доброго дня)

Есть метод записи переменной и он работает нормально:

```
def name=(name)
  if name == ""
    raise "Имя не может быть пустым!"
  end
  @name = name
end
```

Я попытался сократить запись и сделал такую конструкцию:

```
def name=(name)
   name == "" ? raise "Имя не может быть пустым!" : @name = name
end
```

и почему то она не работает, возможно я не правильно понимаю логику этой конструкции? если **name == ""** то выполняется **raise "Name can't be blank!"** в остальных случаях выполняется **@name = name**. Помогите новичку разобраться с вопросом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться guard-условием, используя if-модификатор, вместо полноценного оператора if

```
def name=(name)
  raise "Имя не может быть пустым!" if name.empty?
  @name = name
end
```

Получится и компактно и наглядно. Чтобы сработал ваш вариант, придется расставить скобки

```
def name=(name)
   (name == "") ? raise("Имя не может быть пустым!") : @name = name
end
```